# How to verify (programmatically) if an exe has been tampered or not?

Tags: c++, winapi, ssl-certificate, digital-signature, code-signing

Context : An third party exe tries to communicate with my application. My Application should ensure that the third party exe is not tampered or  modified by anyone other than its owner. Both the External PE and my application runs on the same machine and the external PE relies on the COM interface to fetch the data it needs from my application.

i am to certain extent aware that the sole purpose of signing an executable with the CA certificate is to ensure authenticity and integrity. So I will have to validate the certificate of the external PE to confirm its identity. However i still have the following doubts.

1) Win-API provides WinVerifyTrust and CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy functions. Both of these functions can be used to for trust verification of an executable. So what is the difference?  In which case i should which function?

2) Even if we use these function to verify the certificates, Is it possible that a malicious app can spoof the certificates(pose like a valid exe) or fool it by other means and connect to my application?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What does "connect to my application" mean?

Comment: Say, the third party application , if it is a valid one, is allowed to fetch some data  from my application.  So my application should be able to identify if it is not tampered before it gives out any data to the third party exe.

Comment: what be if your process is tampered ? say malicious code hook WinVerifyTrust  and always return 0 ? usual WinVerifyTrust  used for check file with WTD_CHOICE_FILE in WINTRUST_DATA

Comment: with CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy you need extract certificate from file by self, when WinVerifyTrust do this auto - you need only file path

Comment: And what it will solve? What the problem if anyone else will get that data? You do understand that even with non-tampered exe, data can be captured by intercepting traffic and exchange itself can be tampered with by packet spoofing or just messing with program memory itself?

Comment: This is very wooly. We've no real idea how these processes communicate. Whether or not they are even on the same machine. I think you have serious confusion.

Comment: The communication channel is of utmost importance. If an application tries to verify the identity of a digitally signed executable image, that transfers the relevant information across some communication channel, it is **way** easier to start a man-in-the-middle attack than it is to spoof a digital signature. Given your fuzzy descriptions, it seems likely, that you haven't fully understood the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Step (1) stop the end-user logging in or ever getting Admin rights.  Without this 1st step all bets are off and there is no point in trying anything else.

Comment: @IInspectable  Excuse my Ignorance.  I am an amateur to the security domain. I assumed MITM attacks are not a concern since it is the same machine unless the machine itself is compromised. Both the applications rely on COM for Inter process communication. The External exe communicates with my application through the COM interface.  Further i am more interested in understanding the ways the certificates can be compromised  than the other possible types of attacks. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, i hope the above post and the edits to the question gives a better clarity.

Comment: If you're concerned enough to validate certificates then you should be concerned enough to consider MTM attacks since both require compromise of the machine or the communication channel. If one is a possibility, so is the other.

Comment: 1) What will happen if the app is tampered - you will lose data, your app can be stolen, or what? 2) I suppose you can configure Windows to deny execution of unsigned applications or apps with bad signature. Why is necessary to check by your app and not by OS?

Comment: You can't do this at the app level. You need system level security.